# if clause in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a (join) query that works as expected. But as soon as I add the following column, it does not show any results nor does it complete. (Query running counter keeps growing)

```
IF((d.network_type contains  '_user' AND d.is_network=1),s.impressions,0) AS effimp
```

Is there any other way to optimize this?

---

The full query is as follows and it was working when I tried it in the last month.

```
SELECT s.date_time AS date_time
   , s.requests AS requests, s.impressions AS impressions
   , s.clicks  AS clicks, s.conversions AS conversions
   ,  IF((d.network_type contains  '_user' 
           AND d.is_network=1),s.impressions,0) AS effimp
   , s.total_revenue AS total_revenue
   , s.total_basket_value AS total_basket_value 
   , s.total_num_items AS  total_num_items 
   , s.zone_id as zone_id
FROM company.ox_data_summary s
INNER JOIN company.ox_banners1 AS d ON d.bannerid=s.ad_id 
limit 100
```

Query Failed
Error: Unexpected. Please try again.

If I remove the "IF clause it does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're hitting a query processing bug. We're investigating.

Comment: Using "IF" in join is important. Big Query has disappointed me.

Comment: I'm very sorry to not have a fix or a workaround yet, but this is a tricky issue, and we were unable to reproduce the problem with a simpler join + if statement. Can you give me read access to the datasets involved please (I'm tigani@google.com)? If so that will greatly speed up our debugging process.

Comment: When I use only if clause in select, it does work. But it does not work when selected with other columns.

Comment: We're giving this the highest priority -- two of our engineers have spent considerable amount of time tracking this down and have built custom tools to help isolate the issue. We've got the repro case isolated but still do not have a fix. It doesn't appear to be related to the IF statement -- if you select fewer fields but still keep the IF it should work as a temporary workaround.