# google-bigquery error unexpected please try again

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to run the following query but consistently getting an 'Error: unexpected. Please try again':

```
select sum( ssw.stem_count ) as sum_stem_count, ssw.stem, min( ssw.term )
from ( select * from mediacloud.ssw_2011_11_14_2011_11_20, mediacloud.ssw_2011_11_21_2011_11_27 )
    as ssw left join mediacloud.topic_obama as ssw_q
    on ssw.stories_id = ssw_q.stories_id 
  group by ssw.stem order by sum_stem_count desc limit 1000;
```

The following query works fine:

```
select sum( ssw.stem_count ) as sum_stem_count, ssw.stem, min( ssw.term )
  from mediacloud.ssw_2011_11_14_2011_11_20 as ssw 
      left join mediacloud.topic_obama as ssw_q
    on ssw.stories_id = ssw_q.stories_id 
  group by ssw.stem order by sum_stem_count desc limit 1000;
```

The docs seems to say that subqueries can be used as entries in the from clause, but I can't get this to work.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You may have hit the same issue as here:
[if clause in bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315343/if-clause-in-bigquery)
(I realize no if clause is involved, but it looks to be related). We're actively investigating and hope to have a resolution later today.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've resolved the if clause issue, but I'm still getting the same error on the same query.

Comment: Now I'm getting the unexpected error again.  Any idea what's going on?

Comment: It looks like the issue is you're doing a table union in on the left side of the join, and this causes the query evaluator to require a certain partitioning of the data. Investigating the root cause.

Comment: Thanks.  Seems like a table union on the left side of a join would be a very common thing to do!